# silverlight unit test framework for integration testing

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

I want to use the silverlight unit test framework to integration test my application.

Can I load the entire application as part of a unit test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you have your Unit Test Application setup you would essentially be loading the entire application's assemblies into your test application (with the exception of the Application Resources).  If for some reason you are trying to load the application .xap file this would take some more work, but I'm curious about the use case for doing that.

If you can provide some more concrete examples of what your are trying to test I'll be happy to help.

The sample code from this presentation may help  http://www.bendewey.com/blog/index.php/291/silverlight-unit-testing-novacc

### Update

I haven't tried this before, but you can write a javascript function on your Test Framework webpage that automates the calling of you ScriptableMember then have the TestFramework trigger the automated javascript call this in-turn could call into your ScriptableMember where you could then verify your input.  You will probably have to Register your ScriptableObject twice, once in your production app and once in your Test application (unless you've abstracted this somewhere that it can be called by both applications).

Comment: my app has a scriptablemember javascript that can be called.  I want to call this method and then check a value on the screen to see if it matches based on inputs

Comment: what about all of the resources?  how would that work because the unit test application is different?  Do I have to import all the resource files?  What about the code in app.xaml?

Comment: What I have done in the past was create a Resource dictionary call AppResources.xaml and the applications App.xaml and the Test applications App.xaml would reference the same file as a MergedDictionary.